# Is it possible to span a desktop background across 2 monitors, with a different background on a third?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8

In Windows 8 it's now possible to span a desktop background across multiple monitors, by selecting "span" from the desktop background options. This option spans the image across all of the monitors you have connected.

What I'd like to do is span an image across 2 of my 3 monitors, while putting a different background on the third monitor. I figured out how to set a different background for each monitor *individually* (right-click image, set for monitor *n*), but can't figure out how to mix and match with spanning.

Is there some way to span images across some (but not all) monitors in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect by using an image editor to stretch the large background to the right size and then cut it into two single-screen backgrounds, and then apply those along with the third wallpaper to each monitor individually.

You can also use an image editor to combine the large wallpaper and the small wallpaper into one large, triple-wide wallpaper and then have that stretch across all three monitors.

Comment: This is a possible work-around, and an optional last-resort. I'd really like to be able to do it just using the built-in tools though, without having to mess around with image editing.

Comment: @nhinkle I figured. I don't actually have Win8 yet, so here's hoping someone provides a real answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8, there's a easy way to do that!

Just go to the Personalize panel in CP, then click the first thumbnail in bottom. You will see this screen:

[image]

I recommand using a very large image to do that. I use a `3840x1080` png image to do that on two (2) 1080p monitors. It works perfectly!

Comment: Have you tried this with 3 monitors? What I'm trying to do is get one image stretched across the first 2 monitors, and a _different_ image to show up on the third monitor. What you're showing here works fine to stretch one image across 2 monitors, but doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: It will work across 3 monitors too. But to show a different wallpaper on the third, try DisplayFusion here: http://www.displayfusion.com/

Comment: this question is specifically about having 1 image stretched across 2 monitors and a different on the 3rd, so your answer doesn't really apply.